# How to authenticate mongo dB docker container through MongoDB compass?

Tags: mongodb, docker

Problem:

I have set up a docker container for MongoDB and mongo-express. Both are up and running successfully. This is how my docker-compose configurations.

```
questionsdb:
    container_name: questionsdb
    restart: always
    command: mongod --auth
    environment:
        - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=questions
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=org1234
    volumes:
        - mongo_data:/data/db
    ports: 
        - "27019:27017"

  mongo-express:
    container_name: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
        - mongoadmin_data:/data/dbadmin
    environment:
        #- ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
        #- ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=org1234
        - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=questionsdb
        - ME_CONFIG_OPTIONS_EDITORTHEME=ambiance
        - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL=mongodb://admin:org1234@questionsdb:27017
        - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=admin@myorg.com
        - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=org@1234
        - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=true
    links:
        - questionsdb
```

But when I open the mongo-express nothing showing. Then I look on mongo-express logs. Then I saw this.

```
(node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.

(node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: command listDatabases requires authentication

at Connection.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:453:61)

at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)

at processMessage (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:454:10)

at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:623:15)

at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)

at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)

at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)

at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)

at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)

(node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)

(node:7) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Then I tried to access the MongoDB container through MongoDbComapsss like this.

[image]

but that also failed with giving me authentication failed error. If I remove MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME and  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD it working without any issues. I tried a lot to find a solution to this one. But I was unable to do so. Can someone help me to solve this issue? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this issue can be resolved if you put
USERNAME & PASSWORD
encrypted in BASE64

Replace this

```
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=org1234
```

with

```
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=YWRtaW4=
ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=b3JnMTIzNA==
```

BASE64 Encode & Decoder

```
https://www.base64encode.org/
```